# Duas Intents iniciando a mesma Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Eu tenho um botão para incluir uma Dica e tenho outro botão para editar a Dica já criada. 
Gostaria de usar a mesma Activity de criação, quando for para edição puxaria os dados já criados.
Estou em dúvida como fazer o código do Intent, não estou conseguindo. Não está puxando os dados. Estou tentando assim:

```
{ Intent novadica = getIntent();
        if (novadica==null){

        enviardica.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                ParseObject dica = new ParseObject("Dicas");



                dica.put("nome", edttitulodica.getText().toString());
                dica.put("conteudoDica", edtconteudodica.getText().toString());
                dica.put("resumo", resumoChamadaDica.getText().toString());



                dica.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {


                        Toast.makeText(Inclusaodedica.this, "Dica enviada com sucesso.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
                    }
                });


            }
        });}else{

            Intent editardica = getIntent();
          String rdicaObjectId = editardica.getStringExtra("dicaObjectId");

            final ParseQuery <ParseObject> dica = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Dicas");
            dica.getInBackground(rdicaObjectId, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
                @Override
                public void done(final ParseObject object, ParseException e) {


                    edttitulodica.setText(object.getString("nome"));
                    edtconteudodica.setText(object.getString("conteudoDica"));
                    resumoChamadaDica.setText(object.getString("resumo"));

                    enviardica.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {



                            object.put("nome", edttitulodica.getText().toString());
                            object.put("conteudoDica", edtconteudodica.getText().toString());
                            object.put("resumo", resumoChamadaDica.getText().toString());


                            object.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void done(ParseException e) {


                                    Toast.makeText(Inclusaodedica.this, "Dica alterada com sucesso.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
                                }
                            });





                        }
                    });
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Precisamos de uma descrição mais detalhada do problema. O que é "não está puxando os dados"? Dá algum erro? Alguma linha que era pra dar um resultado dá outro?

Comment: Oi Pablo é o seguinte: eu tenho uma Activity - Incluirdica, e outra Activity - Dica (com um botão editar). A Activity Incluirdica é formada por EditTexts vazios. A Activity Dica, quando click no botão editar - eu queria que abrisse a Activity Incluirdica com os dados da Dica nos EditTexts. Mas não está puxando os dados.

Comment: OK, mas e o erro?

Comment: o erro é que não está trazendo os dados da Intent editardica

Comment: Como você constatou que não está trazendo?

Comment: Pelo simulador.

Comment: Seria mais fácil você passar uma informação por bundle. Um boolean, por exemplo, indicando se o intent está vindo do botão editar ou do adicionar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu passaria um boolean como Extra pra outra Activity:

Ao invés de:

```
startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
```

Faça:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("is_new", true);
startActivity(intent);
```

Na outra Activity, faça a confirmação:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras != null){
   if(extras.getBoolean("is_new", false)){
       //se a váriavel "is_new" estiver como true entra aqui
   }else{
       //se ela estiver false, ou seja, é edição, entra aqui
   }
}
```

Comment: Oi. Perfeito funcionou. Muito Obrigada!!

Comment: Que bom que funcionou! Eu esqueci de mencionar, mas o **false** ali na segunda activity, é um valor padrão, caso o valor da activity anterior venha vazio.